# Unale to connect to the postgres from TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using nestJS to connect to the database with TypeORM as the db package.
My postgres is running in docker with ip 172.17.0.3: 5432

> sudo docker run --name postgre -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -v
> /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres

Here is my storage module file:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { storageConfig, StorageService } from './storage.service';
import { TypeOrmModule} from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Module({
  providers: [StorageService],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      driver: 'pg',
      type: 'postgres',
      host: '172.17.0.3',
      port: 5432,
    
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'user_storage',
      schema: 'public',    
      entities: [User]    
    })
  ]
})
export class StorageModule {}
```

Now with this I tried importing the users.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

and I use repository in  a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserRequest, UserResponse } from './user.models';
import {DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { User } from 'src/storage/entities/user.entity';



@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private readonly _users: Repository<User> 

  constructor(private ds: DataSource) { 
    this._users = this.ds.getRepository(User)
  }

  async create(req: UserRequest) {
    const user = this._users.create()

    user.id = 1
    user.name = req.name
    user.age = req.age
    user.address = req.address
    user.notes = ''

    const saveduser = await this._users.save(user)

    return saveduser.id;
  }
}
```

But I keep getting this error whenever I run:

```
[Nest] 36982  - 07/05/2022, 12:02:19 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application... 
[Nest] 36982  - 07/05/2022, 12:02:20 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "aurora-mysql", "aurora-postgres", "better-sqlite3", "capacitor", "cockroachdb", "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "nativescript", "oracle", "postgres", "react-native", "sap", "sqlite", "sqljs", "spanner".
    at DriverFactory.create (/projects/hw/src/driver/DriverFactory.ts:72:23)
    at new DataSource (/projects/hw/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:139:43)
    at createTypeormDataSource (/projects/hw/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:172:23)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/projects/hw/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:176:46)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /projects/hw/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/projects/hw/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:16:12)
    at /projects/hw/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:174:76
    at Observable._subscribe (/projects/hw/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/observable/defer.ts:55:15) [Nest] 36982  - 07/05/2022, 12:02:20 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... TypeError: this.postgres.Pool is not a constructor
    at PostgresDriver.createPool (/projects/hw/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts:1461:22)
    at PostgresDriver.connect (/projects/hw/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts:340:38)
    at DataSource.initialize (/projects/hw/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:232:27)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/projects/hw/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:179:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone still struggling, another solution for this is to import your ormconfig.js module using commonjs syntax and insert it as the first parameter for TypeORM's forRoot. The reason this happens is because TypeORM does not support TypeScript when applying these settings, so importing your ormconfig.js module using the keyword **import** won't work, because the correct way of doing that in vanilla NodeJS is using require. Also, don't forget to change your ormconfig.ts -> ormconfig.js:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { ReportsModule } from './reports/reports.module';
const settings = require('../ormconfig.js');


@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(settings),
    UsersModule,
    ReportsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: this one works well for me, but instead of using `require` with js file, I've created ts config file and used it instead.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging, I was able to find my mistake. in the users.module.ts I had this code:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

I replaced `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` with `StorageModule` and it started working. The problem was that with `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` as blank, it wasn't able to utilize any configuration that was provided in `StorageModule`
The correct one is below:

```
@Module({
  imports: [StorageModule],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```